# IndexError: string index out of range in LEETCODE problem 5

Tags: python, roman-numerals

In line 6(alternative 8). **I am getting an error if I use value of range(lens), but if I reduce the value of range(lens-1). I am getting an error and not the correct answer.**

For example, for the input "III", I should be getting the value 3, but instead I get the value 2. And for the input "MCMXCIV", I am getting the value 2294 instead of 1994.

In both instances, the last numeral is being skipped out. How to get without causing string index out of range?

And Can someone point out what's going on wrong here?

```
def romanToInt( s: str) -> int:
    lens = len(s)
    ans = 0
    i = 0

    while (i != lens):

    #for i in range(lens):
        
        print(i)
        print(s[i])
        if(s[i] == 'I' ):
            if(s[i+1] == 'V'): 
                ans = ans + 4
                i += 1
            elif(s[i+1] == 'X' ):
                ans = ans + 9
                i += 1
            else:
                ans +=1
                
        elif(s[i] == 'V' ):
            ans += 5

        elif(s[i] == 'X' ):
            if(s[i+1] == 'L'):
                ans += 40
                i += 1
            elif(s[i+1] == 'C'):
                ans += 90
                i +=1
            else:
                ans += 10
        
        elif(s[i] == 'L' ):
            ans += 50

        elif(s[i] == 'C' ):
            if(s[i+1] == 'D'):
                ans += 400
                i += 1
            elif(s[i+1] == 'C'):
                ans += 900
                i +=1
            else:
                ans += 100
        
        elif(s[i] == 'D' ):
            ans += 500
        
        elif(s[i] == 'M' ):
            ans += 1000
        
        i += 1

    return ans

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = romanToInt("III")
    print(a)

    b = romanToInt("MCMXCIV")
    print(b)
```

Comment: You're looking ahead when `i` may be at the last character of your string. `if(s[i+1] == 'V')`. What happens if `i` is already at the last character here?

Comment: Your while loop should be constrained to "< lens-1" as you want to access two characters

Comment: @HeziShahmoon Not always. That would prevent your code reading the last character when it's not part of a group (`IV` vs `V`). More likely OP wants something like `if (i == lens - 1):` before `elif(s[i+1] == 'V'):`, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in a few moments.
That using a check condition would help avoid the index out of range by not accessing s[i+1].

if(i != lens-1 and s[i+1] == 'variable'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an element that is not in your string when `i` is the last index. To prevent index error, you need to check `i` with `lens-1` and run your validations if `i < lens-1`. This way you can prevent `i+1` index error. You also have mistakes in your code because you loop through the string, and you add 9 instead of 4 for the `IV` case (4 for `I` and 5 for `V`).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I figured it out in sometime. But I'm not quite sure about what you mean by " you also have mistakes in your code because you loop through the string, and you add 9 instead of 4 for the IV case (4 for I and 5 for V). "

Comment: I could see `i += 1` statements right now. Without them, for the `IV` case, adding 4 and 5 will result in a wrong answer. I generally look backward if I need to deal with roman numbers. It seems easier to read to me.